# Node fails to run on bootup script

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash

I have a simple init.d script that runs a bash script:

```
#! /bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          registertool
# Required-Start:    $network $local_fs $syslog $remote_fs networking
# Required-Stop:     $network $local_fs $syslog $remote_fs
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Starts registration script
# Description:       Starts the registration script
### END INIT INFO
do_start() {
    cd $APP_DIR
    ./register.sh -v &
    echo $! > "$PID_FILE"
    log_action_msg "Registration started with pid $!"
}

case $1 in
  start)
    do_start
    ;;

  stop)
    log_end_msg 0
    ;;

  restart|force-reload)
    log_end_msg 0
    ;;
  *)
    echo $USAGE >&2
    exit 1
  ;;
esac
```

Inside the script, I define my node as `NODE=$(which node)` and run an application as `$NODE myApp.js`. I have defined the path in the script as

```
PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/bin/:/bin"
```

However, my node is not even called! What am I doing wrong? What else do I need to wait for to boot up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NODE=$(which node)` will search `$PATH` to find the executable.  If your path has not been defined, it won't find anything.  Try having your script log each step so you can see where it goes sideways.

`./register.sh` will depend on the current directory being something specific.  During system startup, `cwd` may not even be defined.

Comment: I forgot to post that, I already have `PATH` defined. I'll update my answer. That is not the issue, and also I specifically go to the drive myself. The file `./register.sh` is called because there are other shell commands that are executing just fine. It fails when it reaches node

Comment: If you wrap the command line that you expect to start node in and echo and redirect it to a /tmp file, what does it look like on system boot?

Comment: `LOCAL=false VERBOSE=true /usr/local/bin/node ./get_register_data.js`

Comment: Does your script `cd` to the location of `get_register_data.js` or does it rely on the current directory being where expected?  If not, try replacing `./get_register_data.js` with an absolute path?

Comment: `cd` goes to where `get_register_data` is. I've even tried absolute path as well. The funny thing is, every once in a while `get_register_data` does run. Something is not ready for Node to run, and I just cannoot figure out what

Comment: My only thought then is redirect both stdout and stderr to a file.  Perhaps node is spewing something meaningful on stderr.